# How to install python module to Nokia Symbian phone?

Tags: python, module, installation, symbian

I want to calculate sunrise/sunset times with my Nokia Symbian phone, but the python code for this needs the pytz module. How do i install the pure python module to Nokia Symbian phone?

Answer (score 0):

Read the "Extending and Embedding PyS60" chapter here: https://garage.maemo.org/frs/download.php/7490/PyS60_2_0_documentation.pdf

But I guess you can simply grab all the useful source codes from that pytz module and try to integrate into your mobile project.